# Finite points from graph of the following equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The graphs of the following equations on the x-y axes have how many
points: no points, a finite number, or infinitely many? $x^2 + y^2 = -4$. $x+y=-4$, $x^2+xy=1$

Don't all of these equations have infinitely many points? You can, for instance, keep adding a tiny tiny value very close to 0 infinitely many times.  Therefore, don't they all have an infinite number of points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they do not all have an infinite number of points. Adding a tiny value close to 0 infinitely many times has nothing to do with this problem.

The graph of an equation is simply the set of all points which satisfy that equation. The graph of an equation has (no points/ a finite number of points / infinitely many points) if there are (no points/ a finite number of points / infinitely many points) which satisfy that equation.

For the graph of $x^2+y^2 = -4$, keep in mind that $a^2 \ge 0$ for any real number $a$. Hence, $x^2 \ge 0$ and $y^2 \ge 0$. Based on this, are there any points which satisfy $x^2+y^2 = -4$?

The graph of $x+y = -4$ is a line. How many points are on a line?

For $x^2+xy = 1$, we can solve for $y$ to get $y = \dfrac{1-x^2}{x} = \dfrac{1}{x}-x$. For how many values of $x$ do we get a value of $y$? That will tell you how many points are on the graph of $x^2+xy = 1$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there are infinite points on a line, and for $x^2+xy=1$, if I'm not mistaken, this also has infinite points, with the exception of $x \ne 0$